# How to partition AWS lambda invocations to independent processing tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-lambda

I am looking for some best practice advice on AWS, and hoping this question won't immediately be closed as too open to opinion.

I am working on a conversion of a windows server application to AWS lambda.
The server runs every 5 minutes and grabs all the files that have been uploaded to various FTP locations.
These files must be processed in a specific order, which might not be the order they arrive in, so it then sorts them and processes accordingly.
It interacts with a database to validate the files against information from previous files.
It then sends the relevant information on, and records new information in the database.
Errors are flagged, and logged in the database, to be dealt with manually.

Note that currently there is no parallel processing going on.  This would be difficult because of the need to sort the files and process them in the correct order.

I have therefore been assuming the lambda will have to run as a single invocation on a schedule.

However, I have realised that the files can be partitioned according to where they come from, and those locations can be processed independantly.
So I could have a certain amount of parallelism.

My question is what is the correct way to manage that limited parallelism in AWS?

A clunky way of doing it would be through the database, something like this:

- A lambda spins up and reads a particular table in the database
- This table has a list of independant processing areas, and the columns: "Status", "StartTime".
- The lambda finds the oldest one not currently
  being processed, registers it as "processing" and updates the
  "StartTime".
- After processing the status is set to "done" or some such.

I think this would work, but it doesn't feel quite right to be managing such things through the database.

Can someone suggest a pattern that my problem fits into, and the correct AWS way of doing this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to run a parallel job on a 5 minute schedule, unless the single-threaded job might not get done in 5 minutes.

Comment: Indeed, that is the scenario I was thinking of.   I think the job will run in time,  but I was considering mitigation just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to do this with parallel lambda invocations, then yes, you should *absolutely* use a database to coordinate their work.

The protocol you're thinking about seems reasonable.  You need to use the transactional capabilities of the database to ensure that the parallel invocations don't interfere with each other, and you need to make sure that the system is resilient to lambda invocations that don't happen.

When your lambda is invoked to handle the event, it should decide how many additional parallel invocations are required, and then make asynchronous lambda calls to run those additional instances.  Those instances should recognize that they were invoked directly and skip that part.

After that, all of the parallel lambda invocations should do *exactly the same thing*.  Make sure that none of them are special in any way, so you don't need to rely on any particular one completing without error.  They should each pull work from a work queue in the DB until all the work is done.

BUT NOTE:  Usually the kind of tasks you're talking about are not CPU-bound.  If that is the case then running multiple parallel tasks inside the *same* lambda invocation will make better use of your resources.  You can do both, of course.